# Expresión Regular en java

Tags: java, regex

Buenas tardes compañeros, me encuentro haciendo una expresión regular en java y tengo ya armada la expresión.

```
^[a-z]+.([a-z]+[0-9]*)?@epn.edu.ec$
```

la expresión debe validar un correo de este tipo:

pepito.delospalotes@epn.edu.ec

mi expresión regular si valida que el dominio sea el indicado, el problema es que necesito que valide después del nombre el punto es obligatorio, y también después del apellido puede o no ir una cifra de hasta dos dígitos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es escapar el punto, recuerda que cuando usas el punto sin más este hace referencia a cualquier tipo de caracter. Así que para escaparlo lo debes expresar como `\.`.

Así tu expresión regular quedaría:

```
^[a-z]+\.([a-z]+[0-9]*)?@epn.edu.ec$
```

Lo cual hace match con:

```
pepito.delospalotes@epn.edu.ec
pepito.@epn.edu.ec
```

Sin embargo puede que el segundo ejemplo no sea algo que busques, si quieres hacer obligatorio el contenido luego del punto tienes que deshacerte del caracter ? que está al lado del capture group entre paréntesis

Así tu expresión quedaría:

```
^[a-z]+\.([a-z]+[0-9]*)@epn.edu.ec$
```

Donde la cadena `pepito.@epn.edu.ec` no haría match.

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando acá:
https://regex101.com/r/GK8qVw/1

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, era justo lo que buscaba. Tenia una duda de saber si se puede poner una restricción de que el nombre y apellido del correo contenga mínimo 4 caracteres ..? eso se podría controlar..?

Comment: @user97805 sí. Si la restricción es que cada uno tenga al menos 4 caracteres `"^[a-z]{4,}\\.[a-z]{4,}[0-9]{0,2}@epn\\.edu\\.ec$"` (si son 4 caracteres en total entre ambos es apenas más complejo, por lo que te diría que hagas una nueva pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que debes hacer es importa esto

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

te explicare un poco de esta exprecion que estoy utilizando
"^[a-z]+.[a-z]+(.[a-z0-9]{1,2})?@epn.edu.ec$"

```
^: indica que la expresión debe coincidir al comienzo del texto.
[a-z]+: coincide con uno o más caracteres en minúscula.
\\.: coincide con un punto literal (se utiliza \\ porque en Java es necesario escapar el carácter \).
([a-z]+[0-9]*)?: coincide con un grupo opcional que puede tener uno o más caracteres en minúscula seguidos de cero o más dígitos.
@epn\\.edu\\.ec: coincide con la dirección de correo electrónico completa con el dominio epn.edu.ec.
$: indica que la expresión debe coincidir al final del texto.
```

eso seria todo lo que necesitas y  ahora solo tocaria validarlo y algo asi seria :

```
   String correo = "pepito@epn.edu.ec";
        String regex = "^[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+(\\.[a-z0-9]{1,2})?@epn\\.edu\\.ec$";
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(correo);
        
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("El correo " + correo + " es válido.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El correo " + correo + " no es válido.");
        }
```

espero que te sirva gracias :D

Comment: Por qué el segundo punto en el regex? (Y te conviene formatearlo como código, sino las ```\\``` no se ven en tu respuesta)